# Unable to run 2 commands in a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to run at least 3 command in a batch file

1. Start CMD
2. Change directory (D drive)
3. Execute command (ipconfig)

So this is how i do it for the first 2 points, but was unable to fulfil the 3rd one.

> start cmd.exe /k "D:" & "ipconfig"

I was unable to execute the ipconfig.

Please help.

Comment: Batch files are already run in command by default so there is no reason to specify cmd.exe in the batch itself. Is this perhaps a homework or schoolwork question?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
cmd.exe /k "cd /D D: && ipconfig"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be something like:

```
@echo off
cd /d d:\
cls
ipconfig
pause
```